# import JSON file returns object, not array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, webpack

Im trying to import a json that contains an array of string arrays. I want to lazy load it

Example json file:

```
[
 ["Autophagy","Inducers","Inhibitors","Signaling Pathway"],
 ["Bacteriology"],
 ...
]
```

If I import the file like this:

```
import content from '../assets/json/myfile.json';
console.log(content)
```

I can see in the console that I have imported an array. But Im trying to lazy load this jsons only when its necessary, so I was trying to do the import like this:

```
const jsonFile = () => import('../assets/json/myfile.json');
jsonFile().then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
});
```

But here in the console I see that data is an object, with the keys being the indexes of the items, plus a "default" key at the end with the whole array.

```
{
 0: ["Autophagy","Inducers","Inhibitors","Signaling Pathway"],
 1: ["Bacteriology"],
 ...
 default: [["Autophagy","Inducers","Inhibitors","Signaling Pathway"],["Bacteriology"],...]
}
```

Is there any way for the promise to automatically import it as an array? It doesnt feel very elegant to do it like this

```
const jsonFile = () => import('../assets/json/myfile.json');
jsonFile().then((data) => {
  const array = data.default;
});
```

Comment: You cannot, using only vanilla JS, import a JSON file. So what bundler are you using? Webpack? Rollup? Typescript compiler? Need a little more data here.

Comment: its a vue application, it uses webpack

Comment: I've added the vue.js and webpack tags for you. Try to include that information in the question in the future, especially if you are not totally up on what is possible in vanilla js vs in frameworks. People subscribe to tags, and you're more likely to get a response from someone who understands the constraints of the problem that way.